# How to order properties alphabetically (Visual Studio 2008)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm really anal and would like to order my class properties alphabetically/by type.

Is this possible using a pre-existing feature in VS, or a macro that can do this?

Eg:

```
public string foo {get; set;}
public string bar {get; set;}
public int fong {get; set;}
public string loo {get; set;}
```

to (if you want to order alphabetically)

```
public string bar {get; set;}
public int fong {get; set;}
public string foo {get; set;}
public string loo {get; set;}
```

or (if you want to order by type, and then alphabeticall)

```
public string bar {get; set;}
public string foo {get; set;}
public string loo {get; set;}
public int fong {get; set;}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know a different solution. Copy your code into `Excel` then copy it back to `Visual Studio`.

1. Copy your text/code in VS
2. Start Excel
3. Insert your text/code in Excel
4. Select you text/code
5. List item
6. Right-click on it
7. Click on sort
8. Click on From A to Z
9. Your text/code is now sorted. Select your text/code in Excel
10. Copy your text/code and paste it in VS

[image]

Comment: Excellent idea! It can be a bit tricky when dealing with different types and the use of non-auto properties..

Comment: @DanAtkinson you could even write your own excel sorting macro, if different types are a problem :)

Comment: You could also do it in Notepad++ for example which has a sorting mechanism, but with functionality like this, it would get quite repetitive copy/pasting between VS and Excel.

Answer (score 2):

Not to my knowledge - but both DevExpress' [CodeRush/Refactor](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/) (through an add-on) as well as [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_formatting.html) through their code formatting features support this.

Marc

Comment: Sadly, CodeRush and Resharper, whilst good products, are quite expensive and something I'm disinclined to pay for it for one small feature (albeit, I'll probably grow to want the other ones). Do you know if this is supported in DevExpress Refactor!™ Pro, which is currently on my machine?

Comment: Yes, both cost money - although there *IS* a free Coderush Xpress version - did you know? Check out:
http://www.devexpress.com/Home/Announces/CodeRushXpress.xml

Comment: Download CodeRush Xpress (for C#) from:
http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/

Comment: And then grab the "CR_ClassCleaner" plugin, which supports ordering your properties, member variables etc. in alphabetical order: http://www.codeplex.com/CRClassCleaner

Comment: Hi Dan - if you have RefactorPro on your machine, you also have the "DXCore" components. As far as I understand the CR_ClassCleaner site on Codeplex, it's a "DXCore plugin" - so chances are it'll work with RefactorPro installed - give it a whirl!